# C# XML reader Search specific packet and return identifier

Tags: c#, xml, linq

so example I have a switch case and I input "1" then it will prompt the user to input the specific pocket, If I inputted "ClientLoginRequest" which is inside the Client Message packets, it should output a string which has the value "CLIENTPC_LOGIN_RESPONSE" how do I do that? My codes can only output a certain node and it's elements, example it outputs the ConnectionPackets as defined by the program so the output is

so here are the codes...

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Xml;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Xml.Linq;

        namespace Packets
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    string result = "C:\\Users\\Ivan.Apungan\\Documents\\PacketTypes.xml";


                    using (var stream = new StringReader(result))
                    {
                        XDocument xmlfile = XDocument.Load(result);

                        var query = from c in xmlfile.Descendants("ConnectionPackets") select c;

                        foreach (var item in query)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                        }


                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

here are the xml file.

```
    <? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

    <Packets>

      <ConnectionPackets>
        <PacketType name = "Handshake" > HANDSHAKE </ PacketType >
        < PacketType name="HandshakeAcknowledgement">HANDSHAKE_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT</PacketType>
      </ConnectionPackets>

      <ClientMessagePackets>
        <PacketType name = "ClientLoginRequest" > CLIENTPC_LOGIN_REQUEST </ PacketType >
        < PacketType name="ClientLoginResponse">CLIENTPC_LOGIN_RESPONSE</PacketType>
      </ClientMessagePackets>

    </Packets>
```

so example I have a switch case and I input "1" then it will prompt the user to input the specific pocket, If I inputted "ClientLoginRequest" which is inside the Client Message packets, it should output a string which has the value "CLIENTPC_LOGIN_RESPONSE" how do I do that? My codes can only output a certain node and it's elements, example it outputs the ConnectionPackets as defined by the program so the output is

```
  <ConnectionPackets>
    <PacketType name = "Handshake" > HANDSHAKE </ PacketType >
    < PacketType name="HandshakeAcknowledgement">HANDSHAKE_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT</PacketType>
  </ConnectionPackets>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple using the System.Xml.Linq extensions to query the xml document. Please let me know if have misunderstood your question.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string command = string.Empty;

        while (command != "exit")
        {
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

            Console.WriteLine("Find packet: ");
            command = Console.ReadLine();

            var element = xml
                  .Descendants()
                  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("name")?.Value == command);

            if (element == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not found");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 20));

        }
    }

    static string xmlString = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
                            <Packets>
                              <ConnectionPackets>
                                <PacketType name=""Handshake""> HANDSHAKE </PacketType >
                                <PacketType name=""HandshakeAcknowledgement"">HANDSHAKE_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT</PacketType>
                              </ConnectionPackets>

                              <ClientMessagePackets>
                                <PacketType name=""ClientLoginRequest"" > CLIENTPC_LOGIN_REQUEST </PacketType >
                                <PacketType name=""ClientLoginResponse"">CLIENTPC_LOGIN_RESPONSE</PacketType>
                              </ClientMessagePackets>

                            </Packets>";

}
```